# method for display

Tags: java

I tried to implement a circular queue, where I would like to display my queue, however the only thing that gets displayed is "Here is my queue" and it just displays "null" rather then printing out the customer added to the queue. I cannot figure out why my queue will not be displayed. I am inserting a picture here to show what I am trying to say [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeOqK.png).

My queue will consists of customers which are moved from the waitingRoom to CustomerQueue. The maximum amount of customers are 33.

Here is my code:

```
package hotelbooking;

public class HotelBooking {
    static int ROOM_CAPACITY = 33;

    private static Customer[] waitingRoom = new Customer[ROOM_CAPACITY]; 
    private static CustomerQueue hotelQueue = new CustomerQueue();
```

This is the method for the user to display the queue.

```
private static void ViewhotelQueue() {
        System.out.println("Here is the queue: ");
        hotelQueue.display();
    }
```

```
package hotelbooking;

public class CustomerQueue {
    private Customer[] queArray = new Customer[HotelBooking.ROOM_CAPACITY];
    private int front = 0;
    private int end = 0;
    private int currentSize = 0; //current circular queue size


    public void display() {   
        //list elements from front to end in the queArray 
        for (int i = front; i < currentSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(queArray[(front+i)%queArray.length] + "");
            queArray[i].display();
        }   
    }
```

Can someone please help me as I am struggling a lot.

Comment: Have you loaded the program in your debugger and single-stepped through it, to see where it's going awry?

Comment: I tried to load it into the debugger but nothing showed up... I am quite new to java even if I would use the debugger I would not know what to do ....  I have inserted an image above to show what I actually mean when it does not allow me to display my queue ... @JimMischel

Comment: What does `CustomerQueue` refer to in `CustomerQueue.display();` in the static `ViewhotelQueue` method, because `CustomerQueue.display()` isn't a static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good you are learning java and data structures..

This might work. please add elements to the Queue and try to display 
and

[image]

Some changes in Customer Queue class

```
private int end = -1;
public void display() {   
    //list elements from front to end in the queArray 
    for (int i = front; i < currentSize; i++) {
        System.out.println(queArray[(front+i)%queArray.length] + "");
    }   
}
```